# New order notification mail not received by admin mail

Tags: magento-1.9

When customer placed order acknowledge send to customer, but admin can't get new order by mail.

[image]

Comment: have you used SMTP pro

Comment: yes am using smtp pro

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify these things:

1. Have you setup cron
2. Admin get all transaction Emails except this Order notification mail
3. Check Magento log files for errors
4. Try to disable SMTP extension.